# How do i print a table in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print the output of the following code in two columns using the python launcher:

```
def main():
    print "This program illustrates a chaotic function"
    n = input("How many numbers should I print? ")
    x = input("Enter a numbers between 0 and 1: ")
    y = input("Enter another number between 0 and 1: ")
    for i in range(n):
        x = 2.0 * x * (1 - x)
        print #??
    for i in range(n):
        y = 2.0 * y * (1 - y)
        print #??

main()
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What is your desired output? What is the underlying data-structure?

Comment: @fluxus you need to specify in which gui framework

Comment: What kind of table? There are an infinite amount of ways to do what you ask. Do you want just a text table to the console, something to the web? It's pretty difficult to help when your question is that ambiguous. Is there anything you've tried so far? Are you getting stuck? Are there any error messages? These are all important information to add when you're asking a question

Comment: WAY more info needed. The question is __definately__ unclear. therefore: -1.

Comment: Edited in content from his comment on my answer below since that is what the question really needed.  Took a bit of license in guessing the indentation but @fluxus feel free to change it if you see something wrong.

Comment: Maybe this can get you started: `python -c 'print "===\n| |"'`

Answer (score 3):

```
for x, y in listOfTwotuples:
    print x, y
```

Given that you've provided no details I've gone ahead and assumed that you've got a list of two-tuples.  Update your question with more info and I'll update my answer to match!

**edit**: with actual details now

If in each loop you store the numbers in a list, you can then use `zip` to get the format needed to use my code snippet above.

So after reading the input in (be careful with `input` by the way, using `raw_input` is better, google why):

```
xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(n):
    xs.append(2.0 * x * (1 - x))
for i in range(n):
    ys.append(2.0 * y * (1 - y))
```

Then you can use `zip` to apply my code snippet above:

```
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    print x, y
```

`zip` takes one list `[0, 1, 2, ...]` and another `[10, 20, 30, ...]` to produce a list of tuples with these lists `[(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30), ...]`.

Comment: Okay I am trying to print the output of the following code using the python launcher:

def main():
 print "This program illustrates a chaotic function"
 n = input("How many numbers should I print? ")
 x = input("Enter a numbers between 0 and 1: ")
 y = input("Enter another number between 0 and 1: ")
 for i in range(n):
  x = 2.0 * x * (1 - x)
  
 for i in range(n):
   y = 2.0 * y * (1 - y)
print ?
   

main()

Comment: Added to the original question, and will update my answer as promised

Comment: If you wanted to print the text in columns, you could use tabs like so:
`print 'x\ty' #newline
for x, y in zip(xs, ys): #newline
    print str(x) + '\t' + str(y)`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>print "a table in python? using two columns"
a table in python? using two columns
```

;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) which will help you to pad strings with spaces to get columns.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is an x and a y value on each line, then once the preliminaries are done, you can say:

```
for i in range(n):
    x = 2 * x * (1 - x)
    y = 2 * y * (1 - y)
    print x,y
```